# Strange SOQL results

Tags: soql

I have these two queries inside my method:

```
global static String doSubmit(String Email){ 
     [SELECT count() FROM Lead WHERE Email =: String.escapeSingleQuotes(Email)]
     [SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE Email =: String.escapeSingleQuotes(Email)]
}
```

I have a lead and a contact with the same email; for the Lead count I get 1, which is what I expect but for the Contact count I get 0, which is not right.
Why do i get different results for similar queries?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but are you sure there's not some white space in one of the data fields on the records?

Comment: and does the user have read permission on the Contact?

Comment: As far as I know you don't have to escape if you use SOQL. If you use dynamic SQL, it's necessary, but it isn't in this case. Concerning the results; Are you really sure the record exists?

Comment: record is there and no white space found

Comment: What abt the read permission on the Contaxct email field as Doug suggested to check? Can you try this using another dummy email which is the same on the Lead and Contact?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the Contact is tied to an Account, unless you're running this query as a user with the View All Data option.

Comment: The public profile has no  View All Data option; Can it be the the public profile does not have read access to Contacts?

Comment: Yes a lack of Read access on Contacts would certainly cause them not to be able to see the records.